# Ansible won't connect via SSH

Tags: linux, ansible

Hi I've recently installed ansible on centos 7  to manage a remote server. I've tried connecting to the server using ansible with ssh and tried pinging the server using the command " ansible -m ping all" i get an error message saying "

```
 "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 176.16.21.138 port 22: Connection timed out", 
    "unreachable": true "
```

I've tried turning off the firewalls, nothing works. I've posted an image of an error mesage i get when i execute the anisble command with the -vvv option/

However  I can manually connect to the server using the ssh command. It just that ansible won't work .
[Image of error message  with -vvv here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4xPk.png)

Comment: Does it take longer than 10 seconds to connect when you connect manually?

Comment: And please don't post screenshots of text that you could copy&paste. Just copy&paste it into your question.

Comment: Check for typos.

Answer (score 2):

Your `-vvv` output shows that Ansible is run with the parameter `-o ConnectTimeout=10`.

There are several reasons that could result in a time longer than 10 seconds for an SSH connection, for example the SSH server trying to look up the hostname of the connecting client is a common culprit that takes some time.

Check the time it takes when you connect your SSH session manually, if it takes too long you have two possibilities:

- check what takes so long and resolve that issue
- increase the `ConnectTimeout` value for your Ansible setup

The first solution should be the preferred one.